# How to re-render PaypalScriptProvider when props change so that it replaces the current script in the HTML head?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, paypal

I am trying to re-render the PayPal script and button in a different language when the locale changes. I thought react components renders when their prop changes, but in this case, the `PayPalScriptProvider` adds a script tag in the HTML but never updates it when the language changes.

Althought `forceReRender={[locale]}` on the PayPalButtons causes the button to re-render, but the script is still loading the initialise language script. I need the script to also re-render with the correct props.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-4rldb2?file=App.tsx

```
export default function App() {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState('zh_HK');
  return (
    <div>
      Current Lang: {locale}
      <button onClick={() => setLocale('en_US')}>EN</button>
      <button onClick={() => setLocale('zh_HK')}>HK</button>
      <PayPalScriptProvider
        key="one-and-only"
        options={{
          locale: locale,
          'client-id': 'test',
        }}
      >
        <PayPalButtons forceReRender={[locale]} />
      </PayPalScriptProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```